# I want to allow only one specific user to delete records of other users in csv via python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

The program starts with the login part and if the user is selected as head admin only then the user can delete other accounts. Otherwise, it is not allowed.

> This is the login part:

```
 ad=input("Enter the ADMIN name:")
    pwd=input("enter the Passward:")
    df=pd.read_csv("admin_list.csv")
    df1=df[(df['Admin']==ad) & (df['Password']==pwd)]
    if(df1.empty):
        print("=X= TRY AGAIN =X=")
    else:
```

> This is my deletion code. But, it is giving ValueError:

```
if (df1['Admin']== "Jhanvi"):
    print(" ")
    add=input("Enter Admin you want to Delete: ")
    df2=pd.read_csv('admin_list.csv')
    df3=df2[df2['Admin']==add]
    if(df3.empty):
        print("---This Admin already not exists---")
    else:
        data=(df2[df2['Admin']==add].index.values)
        df2=df2.drop(data)
        df2.to_csv('admin_list.csv',index=False)
        df2=pd.read_csv('admin_list.csv')
        print("-- ", add, " record is successfully deleted. --")
else:
print("Sorry you are not allowed to remove staff details")
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use a database.  CSV files are plain text and can be opened/read/edited by anyone with access to the file itself - locally or remotely. *If* you wanted to take it a (security) step further, look into password hashing.

Comment: could you show the exact error message output?

Answer (score 0):

The ValueError looks like this:

```py
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

and is raised in this line

```
if (df1['Admin'] == "Jhanvi"):
```

**Solution:** replace `df1['Admin']` with variable `ad`. The currently logged-in user is stored in `ad` while `df1['Admin']` contains all user names.

The following code worked for me:

```py
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df1 = pd.read_csv("admin_list.csv")

    ad = input("Enter the ADMIN name:")
    # login part omitted


    if ad == "Jhanvi": # this is the line that needs to be changed
        print(" ")
        add = input("Enter Admin you want to Delete: ")
        df2 = pd.read_csv('admin_list.csv')
        df3 = df2[df2['Admin'] == add]
        if (df3.empty):
            print("---This Admin already not exists---")
        else:
            data = (df2[df2['Admin'] == add].index.values)
            df2 = df2.drop(data)
            df2.to_csv('admin_list.csv', index=False)
            df2 = pd.read_csv('admin_list.csv')
            print("-- ", add, " record is successfully deleted. --")
    else:
        print("Sorry you are not allowed to remove staff details")
```

A word of warning though: S3DEV's suggestion in the comments is correct. You should not store such data in csv files but use a proper database. SQLite could be enough in the beginning.

Even more important: You should *never, ever* store passwords as plain text. At least store their sha256 hash instead. Even better of course, store a hash plus a random salt.